# How to pass data from MainActivity to class extends View

Tags: android, android-canvas

I need to pass `xPos, yPos` data from `MainActivity` to `MyView` class in order to draw circle everytime `xPos, yPos` are changing.

Here is part of my `MainActivity`:

```
if (!array.isEmpty()) {
            xPos = new  String();
            yPos = new String();
            myView = new MyView(context);

            minIndex = array.indexOf(Collections.min(array));
            xPos = checkXarray.get(array2.get(minIndex));
            yPos = checkYarray.get(array2.get(minIndex));
        }
```

and `MyView` class:

```
public class MyView extends View {
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

int x = 800;
int y = 1200;
int radius = 20;
Paint paint;
public void setXY(String xPos, String yPos){
    this.x = Integer.parseInt(xPos);
    this.y = Integer.parseInt(yPos);
    invalidate();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawCircle(x,y, radius, paint);
}
```

`xPos` and `yPos` are declared as `static` fields. I need to pass `xPos` and `yPos` each time the if statement is true, then draw circle in `onDraw` method based on the data from `MainActivity`. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is your MyView instance in your MainActivity class ? What about to create a method in MyView to set xPos and yPos ? no need for static fields.

Comment: @Nutriz i've just edited the code in my question, added `MyView` instance, created the method but still cant draw the circle where I want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a setXY() method to your view and call it from the activity. Within the method, check (before assigning) if the new values are different to the old ones, and if so, call invalidate() which will make the view render itself again. Finally, assign the new values to your x and y variables of  the view.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i've just updated my answer with some code. I added the method `setXY`, still cant draw the circle where i need to.

Comment: The code looks okay, but you should create and initialize the paint you use, in the constructor of the View, not in onDraw(). onDraw() should execute as quickly as possible. Also, there is no need to call super.onDraw(), I believe. If the circle is not drawn where you want it, check if the coordinates you get/parse are correct. Perhaps you need to do some scaling of the coordinates in relation to the actual size of the view.

Comment: I managed to make it work the way I wanted to. I had to create different constructor of the View class. The code is okay, thanks for help :)